# angular unsubscribe does not work without ngOnDestroy

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscribe, unsubscribe

Unable to unsubscribe on a subscription if used in a public method and not ngOnDestroy.

If have rxjs observable interval that is used to poll an API.
onNgInit I subscribe to that observable as follows:

```
Class .. {
   pollingSubscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
      startPolling();
  } 

  // when this gets triggered my polling subscription stops
  ngOnDestroy() {
      if (this.pollingSubscribe) {
          this.pollingSubscription.unsubscribe();
      }
  }

   startPolling() {
      const pollingInterval: Observable<any> = observable.interval(3000).startWith(0);
      this.pollingSubscription = pollingInterval.subscribe( _ => {
         this.store.dispatch(// trigger my Action);
      });
   }

   // when this gets triggered on a click event my polling subscription still keeps polling.
   stopPolling() {
       if ( // condition true) {
           // on this condition stop polling, FYI this line does get triggered,
           // but there is no effect, it still keeps subscribed.
           this.pollingSubscription.unsubscribe();
       }
   }
}
```

Is there anything wrong that I doing, in the public function stopPolling().
How do I unsubscribe on a condition while still active on a given component.

Thanks.

Comment: where are you making the functional call to stopPolling()?

Comment: its just an example, it can be called anywhere, like a click event.

Comment: I asked because I did not see the functional call where the subscription is unsubscribed from.

Comment: @patz are you sure the condition is true? there is nothing wrong with the code, it should unsubscribe without a problem

Comment: Can you confirm that `this.pollingSubscription.unsubscribe` is called in `stopPolling`? For exmple, by putting a `console.log` just after that line.

Comment: I understand, it does get triggered and the unsubscribe line does execute, but does not take effect.

Comment: maybe the component is instantiated multiple times?

Comment: @ggradnig if that was the case then wouldn't the ngOnDestroy have the same behavior. which is not the case.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what's different in your code, but I've reconstructed it on StackBlitz and can't find any problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sdzxqe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @ggradnig thanks for doing that, it does seem it works as supposed there.

Comment: And `startPolling` is not called multiple times, from somewhere else?

Comment: @ConnorsFan on its only at ngOnInit()

Answer (score 0):

Did your `class` uses `implements OnInit, OnDestroy` ?? may be if your class is not implemented using `OnDestroy` then `ngOnDestroy()` will not be executed. This is [the official link](https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy) for `OnDestroy`

The following snippet shows how a component can implement this interface to define its own custom clean-up method.

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements OnDestroy {
    ngOnDestroy() {
       // ...
    }
}
```